# How can I convert canvas image data into an array of per pixel text values with proper x,y?

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I have a piece of code that generates a random image but I want to parse the image so that I get something like this **that I can write to a file**:

```
[data],[data],[data]
[data],[data],[data]
```

Where the top left data would be the text form of the pixel at 0,0 (assuming 0,0 is top left corner) thus the above data would be a 2x3 pixel image and the 0,1 data would be in the right place.

**So basically if the image is 12x12 pixels then the file would have 12 lines each containing 12 data points (as far as I understand it each pixel has 4 values for color/alpha).**

Here is the loop that creates the image, so maybe there is a way to extract the data in the form above inside here:

```
for(var i = 0, len = image.data.length; i < len; i += 4){
    var x = Math.floor( (i / 4) % dstCanvas.width );
    var y = Math.floor( (i / 4) / dstCanvas.width );

    // since n is -1..1, add +1 and multiply with 127 to get 0..255
    var n = (noise.turbulence(x / gridSize, y / gridSize, 0, dstCanvas.width) + 1) * 127;

    image.data[i] = n;
    image.data[i+1] = n;
    image.data[i+2] = n;
    image.data[i+3] = 255;
}
```

Comment: It's a but unclear for me what you try to do: in what format should the string version of the pixel be in and is it for presentation or transfer? Is the resulting table an actual table or should everything be text? Are the two data lines the same pixels just in two versions (text/numbers) and if the next image line should come underneath or continue horizontally? Please elaborate.

Comment: You said: "Where the top left data would be the text form of the pixel at 0,0 (assuming 0,0 is top left corner) thus the above data would be a 2x3 pixel image and the 0,1 data would be in the right place." - what is "the 0,1 data" and furthermore, what is the "right place" and how do you know - how do you calculate it. As it was for Ken, your question is unclear to me.

Comment: @enhzflep sorry guys, I have added some info in bold that should clear things up...

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware added some detail in bold above

Comment: check this out http://beej.us/blog/data/html5s-canvas-2-pixel/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
var txtFile = '';

for(var i = 0, len = image.data.length; i < len; i += 4){
    var x = Math.floor( (i / 4) % dstCanvas.width );
    var y = Math.floor( (i / 4) / dstCanvas.width );

    // since n is -1..1, add +1 and multiply with 127 to get 0..255
    var n = (noise.turbulence(x / gridSize, y / gridSize, 0, dstCanvas.width) + 1) * 127;

    image.data[i] = n;
    image.data[i+1] = n;
    image.data[i+2] = n;
    image.data[i+3] = 255;

    /// handle textfile lines    
    if (x === 0 && y > 0) {
        /// chop off last comma and add linefeed
        txtFile = txtFile.substring(0, txtFile.length - 1) + '\n';
    }

    /// textual representation
    txtFile += 'rgba(' + n + ',' + n + ',' + n + ', 255),';
}

/// for final line
txtFile = txtFile.substring(0, txtFile.length - 1) + '\n';
```

The text format is just an example as you didn't specify exact format - just adjust as needed.

Then after the loop is done you can convert the "file" into a blob and attach it as a reference to an anchor tag:

```
var file = new Blob([txtFile], {type:'text/text'});
var domURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self,
var url = domURL.createObjectURL(file);

var a = document.getElementById('fileAnchor');
a.href = url;
a.download = 'filename.txt';
```

In your html if you want to have the tag manually created:

```html
<a href="#" id="fileAnchor">Click here to download</a>
```

**[ONLINE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/fawJZ/)**